# How to do linear search using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, search

I'm still new to programming. I just wanted to ask how do I to do linear search using pointers. I wanted to make a book management program and i have made a program with pointers written.

[This is the example of how i want it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg8M8.png)

This is the coding

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 5
using namespace std;
struct record
{
int id;//stores id
float price;//store price
int qty;//stores quantity
record* next;//reference to the next node
};

record* head;//create empty record
record* tail;//the end of the record
void push(record *& head, record *&tail, int id, float price, int qty)
{
if (head == NULL)
{
    record* r = new record;
    r->id = id;
    r->price = price;
    r->qty = qty;
    r->next = NULL;//end of the list
    head = r;
    tail = r;
}
else if (head != NULL && (MAX - 1))
{
    record* r = new record;
    r->id = id;
    r->price = price;
    r->qty = qty;
    r->next = head;
    head = r;
}
}

int  pop(record *&head, record *& tail)
{
if (head == NULL)
{
    cout << "No record in memory" << endl;
}
 else if (head == tail)
 {
    cout << "The record "<<"ID: " << head->id << "\nPrice: " << head->price             << "\nQuantity: " << head->qty << "\n" << "was deleted" << endl; //CORRECTION  HERE
}
else
{
    record* delptr = new record;
    delptr = head;
    head = head->next;
    cout << "The record " << delptr->id << ", " << delptr->price << ", " << delptr->qty << " was deleted" << endl; //CORRECTION HERE
    delete delptr;

}
return 0;
}


void display(record *&head)
{
record* temp = new record; //CORRECTION HERE
temp = head;
if (temp == NULL)
{
    cout << "No record in memory" << endl;

}
else
{


        cout << "Record : " << endl;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout <<"\nID: "<< temp->id << "\nPrice: " << temp->price << "\nQuantity: " << temp->qty <<"\n"<< endl;  //CORRECTION HERE
            temp = temp->next;
        }

  }
}

  int LinearSearch(record *&head) {


}

char menu()
{
char choice;

cout << "\t::MENU::\n" << endl;
cout << "1. Add new record\n" << endl;
cout << "2. Delete record\n" << endl;
cout << "3. Show record\n" << endl;
cout << "4. Quit\n" << endl;
cout << "-----------------------\n" << endl;
cout << "\nEnter selection : " << endl;
cin >> choice;
return choice;
}

int main()
{
record* head;
record* tail;
head = NULL;
tail = NULL;
char choice;
do
{
    cout << "---------------------- - \n" << endl;
    choice = menu();
    switch (choice) {   //CORRECTION HERE
    case '1':
        int id, qty;
        float price;
        cout << "Enter ID:";
        cin >> id;   // Please correct yourself here, what is r here, r is not declared anywhere
        cout << "\nEnter Price: ";
        cin >> price;
        cout << "\nEnter Quantity: ";
        cin >> qty;
        push(head, tail, id, price, qty);
        break;
    case '2':
        pop(head, tail);
        break;
    case'3':
        display(head);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Quiting...\n";
    }

} while (choice != '4');

return 0;
}
```

How do I write linear search of pointer code for this coding? I tried finding examples throughout the web and when i execute it, it didn't work so i just leave it blank.

Comment: Linear Search is nothing but traversing the linked list. Please read more about it and try to implement.

Comment: I'd advise using standard containers. Vector or list. Then you will have find function you can use.

Comment: Agree with Paul. First learn the basics of (C++) programming using the predefined data structures. You need to learn pointers to _implement_ datastructures yourself, but you should already be proficient in the _use_ of datastructures at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I saw you have a list and you are dealing with pointers.

If you want to do linear search in a record id, for example, you can do it like this:

```
record *aux = head;
while(aux != NULL){
    if(aux->id == id_you_want_to_find){
        printf("I found it\n");
    }
    aux = aux->next;
}
```

you usually use `object.attribute` to access the attributes of common objects, but when you have a pointer to an object, you must do `pointerToObject->attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one if you want but there is no need to when there already exists libraries that do this for you. Since you are using a list structure I show this using a simple `std::list`. You could also change this to a `std::vector` and just do a simple for loop iteration using index notation since the speed of search through them is constant as opposed to linear. Here is one method of doing a search through a list linear.

```
#include <list>

record* searchRecords( std::list<record>& records, int id ) {
    if ( records.empty() ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid list of records: list is empty.";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream ); // Not Written, but what should be done instead of returning.
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::list<record>::iterator it = records.begin();
    while ( it != records.end() ) {
        if ( it->id == id ) {
            return (&(*it));
        } 
        ++it;               
    }

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " No entry found in search with ID{" << id << "}.";
    Logger::log( strStream, Logger::LOGGER_INFO ); // Not implemented here same as above for ExceptionHandler
    return nullptr;
}
```

Since linked lists are not associative they Must be traversed from beginning to end for every entry N in the list to either insert, find or delete. The time complexity here is linear.

If you want faster time insertion time with large lists you can use `<multiset>` if there may be duplicate items or `<set>` if every known item is unique. These have instant insertion. If you want constant search and don't care about insertion time then `<vector>` is what you would want.

Answer (score 0):

The normal answer would be: don't write a linear search yourself, it's called `std::find_if`. However, C++ expects that your datastructure exposes *iterators*. An iterator refers to a record (or the end of your list). You get the actual record by calling `operator*` on the record, and you get the next record by calling `operator++`.

Yes, this is similar to pointers. That's intentional; pointers *are* iterators for contiguous arrays.  That means you can call `std::find_if` on an array. But since you chose to implement a linked list instead of an array, you'd' need to implement your own iterator class.